server.get_channel() returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
I'm trying to make an embed with a button, and when you click on the button creates a channel and the bot DM you with a embed, but i got an error trying to get the channel by bot.get_channel(channel_id)
This is my code:
try:
    server = await bot.fetch_guild(server_id)
    channel = server.get_channel(channel_id)

    view = View()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
else:
    embed.set_author(name=server.name, icon_url=server.icon.url)

    await interaction.response.defer()
    await channel.send(embed=embed, view=view)

Also i try debug it using
print(channel)
print(channel.id)

Output:
None129
129xxxxxxxxxxxx6

OBS: I use interaction.response.defer() for the command, because it is log and have a delay to send.

When you look at the documentation for Bot.fetch_guild it clearly says that you will not receive the channels and members... You need to use Guild.fetch_channel rather than Guild.get_channel

Hi Lukasz, i made it to channel = await server.fetch_channel(channel_id) and remove the await interaction.response.defer() and works! thank you very much.

Try to use fetch_channel() method

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

It seems that you are trying to get a channel object using a channel Id. You will need to use the guild.fetch_channel(id=channel_id) instead of get_channel(). You might benefit from doing a bit of reading in the discord.py docs which will most likely hold a lot of the answers you might be looking for.
